# query the accont records based on distance

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

```
public String distance=50;
String units='mi';
//lat,lon has latitude and longitude values
List <Account> Addd =database.Query('Select Name,Phone,BillingLatitude,BillingLongitude from Account WHERE 
distance(BillingAddress, geolocation(:lat, :lon), :units) < distance 
ORDER BY distance(BillingAddress, geolocation(:lat, :lon), :units)
LIMIT 20')
```

When i am trying to execute the above query to fetch the account records near 50kms radius, getting the below error:

```
expecting a string literal, found ':'
```

can anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

Apex bind variables are not supported in Location-Based SOQL queries. You need to use `String.format` or regular string concatenation instead.

```
String lat = '0';
String lon = '0';
String distance = '50';
String units = 'mi';

String query = 'SELECT Name, Phone, BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude ' + 
    'FROM Account ' + 
    'WHERE distance(BillingAddress, geolocation({0}, {1}), \'\'{2}\'\') < {3}  ' +
    'ORDER BY distance(BillingAddress, geolocation({0}, {1}), \'\'{2}\'\')   ' +
    'LIMIT 20';

List <Account> Addd = database.Query(String.format(query, 
    new List<String> { lat, lon, units, distance }));
```

See [Location-Based SOQL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm) for more information.

> ### Location-Based SOQL Query Considerations
>
> Location-based queries are supported in SOQL in Apex and in the SOAP and REST APIs. Keep in mind these considerations.
>
> - DISTANCE and GEOLOCATION are supported in WHERE and ORDER BY clauses in SOQL, but not in GROUP BY. DISTANCE is supported in SELECT clauses.
>     DISTANCE supports only the logical operators > and <, returning values within (<) or beyond (>) a specified radius.
> - When using the GEOLOCATION function in SOQL queries, the geolocation field must precede the latitude and longitude coordinates. For example, DISTANCE(warehouse_location__c, GEOLOCATION(37.775,-122.418), 'km') works but DISTANCE(GEOLOCATION(37.775,-122.418), warehouse_location__c, 'km') doesn’t work.
> - Apex bind variables aren’t supported for the units parameter in DISTANCE or GEOLOCATION functions. This query doesn’t work.
>
>   ```
>   String units = 'mi';
>   List<Account> accountList =
>       [SELECT ID, Name, BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude
>       FROM Account
>       WHERE DISTANCE(My_Location_Field__c, GEOLOCATION(10,10), :units) < 10];
>   ```